# Highlight nodetext and slice on mouse over on the particular arc or slice

Tags: d3.js

I want to highlight nodetext when mouse over on the particular arc or slice.
Level 1 on mouse over the arc or slice gets highlighted on mouse over but not nodetext. 
And for level 2 on mouse over the arc or slice highlighted but not nodetext.
If I run them independently it is running. When I run only slice highlight code, it works, when I run nodetext highlight it works, but not both.

To highlight slice I used following code

```
    var typeMouseOver = function (d, i) {                

            var thisObject = d3.select(this);
            var typeValue = thisObject.attr("type_value");
            var strippedTypeValue = typeValue.replace(/ /g, "_");


            var pie1ArcsSelector = "." + "pie1-" + strippedTypeValue;
            var selectedArcs = d3.selectAll(pie1ArcsSelector);                       
            selectedArcs.style("fill", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.data.SectionOverColor); })               
            //alert(typeValue);

            var pie2ArcsSelector = "." + "pie2-" + strippedTypeValue;
            var selectedArcs = d3.selectAll(pie2ArcsSelector);               
            selectedArcs.style("fill", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.data.SubGroupsOverColor); })                        

            };

        var typeMouseOut = function() {            

            var thisObject = d3.select(this);
            var typeValue = thisObject.attr("type_value");                
            var strippedTypeValue = typeValue.replace(/ /g, "_");

            var pie1ArcsSelector = "." + "pie1-" + strippedTypeValue;
            var selectedArcs = d3.selectAll(pie1ArcsSelector);               
            selectedArcs.style("fill", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.data.SectionUpColor); })

            var pie2ArcsSelector = "." + "pie2-" + strippedTypeValue;
            var selectedArcs = d3.selectAll(pie2ArcsSelector);              
            selectedArcs.style("fill", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.data.SubGroupsUpColor); })              

        };
```

To highlight nodetext I used following code

```
     var LabelMouseOver = function () {
                     d3.select(this).select("text")
                     .style("fill", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.data.SectionFontOverColor); })
                 };
```

The code looks something as follows when both are combined i.e. slide highlight and nodetext highlight,

```
 var typeMouseOver = function (d, i) {

            d3.select(this).select("text")
                .style("fill", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.data.SectionFontOverColor); })


            var thisObject = d3.select(this);
            var typeValue = thisObject.attr("type_value");
            var strippedTypeValue = typeValue.replace(/ /g, "_");


            var pie1ArcsSelector = "." + "pie1-" + strippedTypeValue;
            var selectedArcs = d3.selectAll(pie1ArcsSelector);                       
            selectedArcs.style("fill", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.data.SectionOverColor); })                
            //alert(typeValue);
            //alert("#text");

            var pie2ArcsSelector = "." + "pie2-" + strippedTypeValue;
            var selectedArcs = d3.selectAll(pie2ArcsSelector);               
            selectedArcs.style("fill", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.data.SubGroupsOverColor); })                        

            };

        var typeMouseOut = function () {


            d3.select(this).select("text")
                .style("fill", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.data.SectionFontUpColor); })

            var thisObject = d3.select(this);
            var typeValue = thisObject.attr("type_value");                
            var strippedTypeValue = typeValue.replace(/ /g, "_");

            var pie1ArcsSelector = "." + "pie1-" + strippedTypeValue;
            var selectedArcs = d3.selectAll(pie1ArcsSelector);               
            selectedArcs.style("fill", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.data.SectionUpColor); })

            var pie2ArcsSelector = "." + "pie2-" + strippedTypeValue;
            var selectedArcs = d3.selectAll(pie2ArcsSelector);              
            selectedArcs.style("fill", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.data.SubGroupsUpColor); })              

        };
```

But the third code snippet does not work, I could not get any trace why it does not work, nor I understand what goes wrong when they are combined. When I add code for node text hover in type mouse hover it only highlight slice not node text and for label mouse over it highlight only text not slice. How to get text value and its correlated Id in my function, so that I can use it in both for level 1 and level 2. I need both slice highlight and nodetext highlights both simultaneous as per their respected ids. Please help.

Platform Windows 10
Visual Studio 2013
d3.v4.min.js

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve the problem.
I kept the both functions separate. Now they are working fine, Please have a look for label highlight function.

var MouseOverLevel1Label = function (d, i) {

```
            var thisObject = d3.select(this).select("text");
            var LText = thisObject.attr("L_Text");
            var strippedTypeValue = LText.replace(/ /g, "_");


            var pie1Label = "." + "pie1-" + strippedTypeValue;
            var selectedText = d3.select(pie1Label);
            selectedText.style("fill", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.data.SectionFontOverColor); });               

            var pie2Lable = "." + "pie2-" + strippedTypeValue;
            var selectedText = d3.selectAll(pie2Lable);
            selectedText.style("fill", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.data.SubGroupsFontOverColor); })


        };
```